# Kaa User Configuration Sync is slow

Tags: kaa

After I attach user(owner) to an endpoint, the user configuration sync is slow at the beginning. Meaning the user configuration update on Kaa server is not propagating to endpoints. I takes a while for this to happen and after a lot of attempts, the configuration update starts working. Can you please clarify, why this is happening and is there a work around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of KAA do you use? What attempts did you do to achieve configuration update? Do you test this feature on Kaa ConfigurationDemo, if not, test on the one, your endpoint should get config updates immediately.

Comment: @KirillLiubun
 Sorry about the confusion. Yes, Config updates are propagating immediately. Kaa would send an update only when there is a change in config values. If I specify the same config values as the current config again, It would not send the config update.

Comment: It is expected behavior, server will send update only if hash sum  of config are changed

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Kaa would send an update only when there is a change in config values. If I specify the same config values as the current config again, It would not send the config update.